# How does the explicit binding using call() works in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, this

If null or nothing is passed in call(), would it be considered as implicit binding?
What should be the output of the following code? Isn't it should be 2? I am getting 'undefined'.

```
function foo() {
console.log( this.a );
}

var a = 2;

foo.call( null ); // 2
```

Comment: From mdn; "If the method is a function in non-strict mode, null and undefined will be replaced with the global object"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an implicit binding, you can check that with `console.log(this);`. It prints the global object. So, when run in my browser, your code prints `2`.

However, such `var a = 2;` statement [works differently in Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global): it does not create a property of the global object. So `this.a` tries to access a non-existing member which results in `undefined`.

Comment: Additional info: the interactive Node console returns 2 as well (non-strict code) as it creates a global object.